# how to show all integers of an array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm new for ruby. Trying to get all numbers in an array with an method.

```
x = [1..10]
```

expected result.

```
=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you type `[1..10]`, what you actually have is an [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html) containing a single [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html) object. If you want an array of FixNums, you actually drop the `[]`s and call `to_a` on the range itself:

```
irb(main):006:0> x = (1..10).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: I know that there is a method to call all numbers in array.

Comment: (1...10) is still called array? not [] ?

Comment: `(1..10)` is a Range. It represents a sequence of numbers. @Andrew Lorente is correct about the issue with your code. I have also updated my answer to give correct output. But more importantly, I think you need to visit [TryRuby.org](http://tryruby.org). I think your issue stems mostly from needing to learn Ruby fundamentals.

Comment: `[*1..10] #=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` is another common way of constructing the array.

Answer (score 2):

you want to display it?

```
# This dumps the object to console

x = (1..10).to_a
puts x.inspect

# This prints items individually...

x = (1..10).to_a
x.each do |num|
    puts num
end

# This prints only numbers....

x = (1..10).to_a
x.each do |num|
    if num.is_a?(Integer)
        puts num
    end
end
```

Comment: there is simple method like x.inspect I couldn't find it on ruby methods.

Comment: i want to get result as  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Comment: The problem is that `[1..10]` is a single-element list containing a range, not a 10-element list of numbers. See my answer below.

Comment: `puts (1..10).to_a.inspect` is what you want